# How to find missing Await on Async function calls in Node+Typescript+VSCode?

Tags: node.js, typescript, async-await, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

We've deployed bugs in our node app b/c we forgot to prefix async function calls with "await".

Example:

```
const getUsers = async () => db.query('SELECT * from Users');

const testMissingAwait = async () => {
  const users = getUsers(); // <<< missing await
  console.log(users.length);
};

testMissingAwait();
```

Is there an easy way to find async function calls missing the await keyword?

Failing that, how much effort would it be to write a Visual Studio Code extension that flags these automatically? (I'm up for tackling if anyone can point me in the right direction).

Comment: does that function even need to be async? does it gain anything at all? (getUsers)

Comment: Are you using typescript in this project? If so, it should have captured that error at compile since the type `Promise<xxx>` has no property 'length'.

Comment: @CRice that works if you do "users.length" because Promise has no property 'length', but if you forget to await an async function that has no return value, then Typescript won't help you with this mechanism. Does anyone know if there's a Typescript setting (or other linter) that can detect async function calls that you're not awaiting and flag them as possible errors (that you could use a directive to explicitly ignore only when you want to kick off async work and not wait for it)?

Comment: Actually looks like there's a tslint rule to detect "floating" promises called no-floating-promises - https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/no-floating-promises/, https://github.com/palantir/tslint/pull/1632

Comment: Is there something in ESLint for this, too? `require-await` isn't it.

Comment: @user1278519 did you find a solution for eslint?

Answer (score 6):

TypeScript compiler doesn't provide a compiler option for that. However, TSLint 4.4 provides an option to detect floating promises. You can read this blog post for more detailed answer: [Detect missing await in typescript](https://www.meziantou.net/2017/11/20/detect-missing-await-in-typescript)

Download TSLint:

```
npm install -g tslint typescript
```

Configure TSLint:

```
{
    "extends": "tslint:recommended",
    "rules": {
        "no-floating-promises": true
    }
}
```

Run TSLint:

```
tslint --project tsconfig.json
```

If there are floating promises in your code, you should see the following error:

> ERROR: F:/Samples/index.ts[12, 5]: Promises must be handled appropriately

Comment: Yes, that works, but VSCode problems tab shows less errors than running tslint manually (for example tslint error when you forgot the await is not present in problems tab)

Comment: I also had VS Code not showing all errors that ESLint cli could detect. Installing the ESLint VS Code plugin fixed that.

Answer (score 3):

TypeScript already does this

```
// users is a Promise<T>
const users = getUsers(); // <<< missing await

// users.length is not a property of users... then and catch are
console.log(users.length);
```

You can find situations where you won't be told about your mistake - where the types are compatible, for example I missed an await here:

```
function delay(ms: number) {
    return new Promise<number>(function(resolve) {
        setTimeout(() => {
            resolve(5);
        }, ms);
    });
}


async function asyncAwait() {
    let x = await delay(1000);
    console.log(x);

    let y = delay(1000);
    console.log(y);

    return 'Done';
}

asyncAwait().then((result) => console.log(result));
```

Because `console.log` doesn't cause any type incompatibility between my numbers and my promises, the compiler can't tell I have made a mistake.

The only solution here would be a type annotation... but if you're gonna forget an await, you're just as likely to forget a type annotation.

```
let y: number = delay(1000);
```

Comment: This only works if you expect a return value from the Promise-returning function. If you instead call the function without assigning the result to a variable but still need to `await` it to ensure things happen in the right order, you won't get notified about your mistake.

Answer (score 3):

[tslint is deprecated](https://blog.palantir.com/tslint-in-2019-1a144c2317a9) but [typescript-eslint](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint) has a rule for this: [`no-floating-promises`](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/main/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/no-floating-promises.md)

> This rule forbids usage of Promise-like values in statements without handling their errors appropriately ... Valid ways of handling a Promise-valued statement include `await`ing, returning, and either calling `.then()` with two arguments or `.catch()` with one argument.

To use it, you'll need to set up typescript-eslint:

1. Install dependencies

   ```
   npm install --save-dev eslint @typescript-eslint/parser @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin
   ```
2. Modify your `.eslintrc` file

   These are the minimum required settings; see the documentation for more options (https://typescript-eslint.io/docs/linting/linting):

   ```json
   {
     "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
     "parserOptions": { "project": "./tsconfig.json" },
     "plugins": ["@typescript-eslint"],
     "rules": {
       "@typescript-eslint/no-floating-promises": ["error"]
     }
   }
   ```

If there are places where you want to call an async function without using `await`, you can either:

- Use the `void` operator as mentioned in the [documentation for the rule](https://typescript-eslint.io/rules/no-floating-promises/), e.g.

  ```
  void someAsyncFunction();
  ```
- Or just change `error` to `warn` in the `.eslintrc` configuration above

Next time you run eslint you should see the rule applied:

```bash
$ npm run lint
...
./src/database/database.ts
  219:7  warning  Promises must be awaited, end with a call to .catch, end with a call to .then with a rejection handler or be explicitly marked as ignored with the `void` operator  @typescript-eslint/no-floating-promises
```

Since you mentioned VS Code specifically, this also integrates great with the [ESLint plugin](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dbaeumer.vscode-eslint):

[image: vscode showing no-floating-promises rule]