How do I get vscode to warn me of all missing awaits?
I want vscode to warn me when I am calling an async function, but have forgot to await it.
For example:
const promiseFn: Promise<string> = async () => {
  return 'i am an async function';
}

const promiseReturn1 = promiseFn(); // should show a warning

const promiseReturn2 = await promiseFn(); // this is good

I know I can hover over the functions to see if they return promises or whatever, but I want it to be evident at face value.
I have tried setting this up through eslint, ts-eslint, etc. and it's a giant pain in the behind and doesn't even work properly.
If there is some extension or other method I can use to do this, I would appreciate it.

Typescript warns you when you try to do something with a Promise, like promiseReturn1.charAt(0) Both lines are technically valid. You might need to make an ESLint plugin for what you want.

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46798354/how-to-find-missing-await-on-async-function-calls-in-nodetypescriptvscode an answer may be there.

what even is happening with the type annotation of promiseFn

Instead of creating additional opinionated diagnostics in your editor, you can lean into the built-in capabilities of the TypeScript language server and IntelliSense that are included in VS Code to help inform you about the types in your code.
VS Code includes a collection of features called inlay hints that aren't enabled by default for JS/TS. The documentation describes it this way:

Inlay hints add additional inline information to source code to help you understand what the code does.

This sounds to me exactly like the kind of functionality that could help you notice the things you're missing.
You can check out the documentation to understand how each setting works, but here are a couple of screenshots comparing your example code with {java|type}script.inlayHints.variableTypes.enabled off and on:


"typescript.inlayHints.variableTypes.enabled": false (default)



"typescript.inlayHints.variableTypes.enabled": true

Being able to see the additional type information will assist you in making sure you're not forgetting to await a promise when you intend to.

Nice tip! Unfortunately it helps only when storing the return value. It does not kick in when just calling the async function for side effect.

^ @ghybs Variable types aren’t the only inlay hint option, just the one that was relevant to the example code. The linked documentation describes the other options, too. The question reads more XY to me: asking for a lint rule to supplement a lack of experience with certain syntax/types, so I thought louder type hints would better address the more fundamental problem.
